# Two hollow magnetic spheres, one slightly smaller inside it same polarity facing each other

Tags: magnetic-fields

If you have a magnet the shape of a sphere (hollow) and a slightly smaller magnetic sphere inside it (same polarity facing each other)
Will the inside sphere "float" inside the larger sphere? Say for example the outside of the inner sphere is positive and the inside of the outer sphere is also positive, then all points between the two spheres ( to infinity would repel)
The inside ball should float being repelled from all sides and be suspended?

Comment: @BrendanDarrer Please stop frivolous edits.  In particular, adding "Is this correct" changes  the tone of the post to a "check-my-work" question, and this kind of question is  considered very negatively on the site.

Answer (score 1):

A uniformly magnetised spherical shell generates a null magnetic field inside it. This is analogous to a uniformly polarised spherical shell in electrostatic. In this case it is simpler to see as the polarised shell can be seen as two slightly shifted, uniformly, oppositely charged spheres. The field generated inside each of these shells is null (Newton's theorem), so their combination is zero as well.

Thus, the small magnetic ball is under the influence of no magnetic field, it is as if it's in vacuum, unless another exterior force (gravity ...) acts on it. Note that this result is due to the highly symmetric nature of the problem, any slight modification of it would probably change the result and give a net force on the inner magnet.

Hope this helps.